# Is removeUpdates() optional when changing GPS update time?

Tags: android

After looking at Android source code I found that `requestLocationUpdate()` contains `removeUpdates()`. But I'm not really familiar with low level android code. is it safe to just call `requestLocationUpdate()` when I want to receive updates in different time interval? I want to avoid `removeUpdates()` because it seems causing some problems on some of my test devices. and also I want to save power by reduce the function calls.
android source:http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/location/ILocationManager.java?av=f

Here is my code, when user starts moving or stops moving this code will be called to reduce or increase the time interval between each update.

    `time=newTime;
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    time,
                    distance, locationListener);`

Comment: what problems are you facing the with that method

Comment: removing updates is necessary  when you want to update a new location at later after some time. You can call it when you got the location and next time you want to get the new location

Comment: `removeUpdates()` sometimes crash the phone's gps when used before `requestLocationUpdate()` . it also depends on the device and some random variables. I was unable to recreate the crash. it happens probably 3/10 times on some less popular phones. On other devices removeUpdates() works fine. After I removed removeUpdates() all my tests went fine so far